# Laravel Application Vite path is not correct

Tags: laravel, vite

I have developed a Laravel 10 application on my computer. In order to see the page styled during development phase, I first run

```
npm run dev
```

command. It works well. After I decided to upload the application to the server (my sharing host) I run

```
npm run build
```

command on my local computer too. It produced a "build" folder in the root directory. Then I uploaded it too via FTP to the root directory my sharing host.

The page is loaded but styles and js files are not. After inspecting the page source I found something interesting.

In the source code of the page it tries to call the css and js files from "build" directory. I also copied the build folder into "public" folder.

```
<link rel="preload" as="style" href="http://mylaravelsite.com/build/assets/app-14edade9.css" />
<link rel="modulepreload" href="http://mylaravelsite.com/build/assets/app-afee69e6.js" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://mylaravelsite.com/build/assets/app-14edade9.css" />
<script type="module" src="http://mylaravelsite.com/build/assets/app-afee69e6.js"></script>
```

When I insert /public into the path on the loaded page:

```
<link rel="preload" as="style" href="http://mylaravelsite.com/public/build/assets/app-14edade9.css" />
<link rel="modulepreload" href="http://mylaravelsite.com/public/build/assets/app-afee69e6.js" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://mylaravelsite.com/public/build/assets/app-14edade9.css" />
<script type="module" src="http://mylaravelsite.com/public/build/assets/app-afee69e6.js"></script>
```

The page is styled as desired. There is not "hot" file in the public directory.

Is it a SSL certifcate error or something else?

Comment: Your apache/nginx config is wrong, it should not point to the root directory but the public directory. Try to see if you can change the destination directory in our hosting provider dashboard. It should be something like `/var/www/laravelsite/public`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the problems stem from .htaccess file. I do not know if I am doing right but after changing one line in the .htaccess all the problems have gone.

```
Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
RewriteEngine On

# Allow Installatron requests
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} deleteme\.\w+\.php
RewriteRule (.*) - [L] 

#RewriteRule ^ index.php [L] Removed this line
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L] #added this line instead
```